# Why does this C++ / OpenGL program run twice?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

After most of the curriculum, they spring C++ on us for the senior year.  Sigh.  So I'm underwater trying to learn it and OpenGL, the latter being the actual subject of the class.

Please, why does this thing run twice?  This assignment has already been turned in and graded, so but I just can't find any good online guide to OpenGL.  Thanks for any thoughts.

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>

int width = 800, height = 600;
float xmin = -(width / 2), ymin = -(height / 2), xmax = width / 2, ymax = height / 2;
GLubyte bitmap[72] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x40, 0x00, 0x02,
0x20, 0x00, 0x04,
0x10, 0x38, 0x08,
0x09, 0x63, 0x10,
0x06, 0x00, 0xA0,
0x08, 0x00, 0x20,
0x10, 0x00, 0x10,
0x10, 0x00, 0x10,
0x10, 0x00, 0x08,
0x20, 0x00, 0x08,
0x20, 0x10, 0x08,
0x20, 0x18, 0x08,
0x10, 0x14, 0x08,
0x10, 0x12, 0x10,
0x10, 0x11, 0x10,
0x08, 0x10, 0x20,
0x04, 0x10, 0x40,
0x01, 0x87, 0x00,
0x00, 0x78, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

void init(void) {
    // Set display-window color to white.
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    // Set projection parameters.
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax);
    // Clear display window.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// Windows redraw function
void winReshapeFcn(GLint newWidth, GLint newHeight) {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-(GLdouble)width / 2, (GLdouble)width / 2, -(GLdouble)height / 2, (GLdouble)height / 2);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void drawText() {
    int x = (int) xmin + 20, y = (int) ymax - 20, count = 0;
    char what [] = { 'R', 'e', 'c', 't', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'l', 'e', 's' };
    float color = 1.0;

    glRasterPos2i(x, y);
    do {
        glColor3f(color,color,color);
        color = color - 0.1;
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, what[count]);
        y = y - 20;
        glRasterPos2i(x, y);
        count = count + 1;
    } while (count <= 9);
}

void drawRectangles() {
    int h = (int) ymax, x1 = -h, y1 = h, x2 = h, y2 = -h, count = 0, delta, factor = 5;

    do {
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2i(x1,h);
            glVertex2i(h,y1);

            glVertex2i(h,y1);
            glVertex2i(x2,-h);

            glVertex2i(x2,-h);
            glVertex2i(-h,y2);

            glVertex2i(-h,y2);
            glVertex2i(x1,h);
        glEnd();
        h = h - factor; delta = factor * count;
        x1 = -h + delta; y1 = h - delta; x2 = h - delta; y2 = -h + delta;
        count = count + 1;
    } while (x1 < h);
}

void drawBitmaps() {
    int count = 0;
    GLfloat xorigin = xmin + (xmax - ymax) / 2.0;

    // Needed for reading from memory. 1 indicates byte alignment
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    // Center the bitmap image
    glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
    do {
        glBitmap(24.0, 24.0, xorigin, ymax, 0.0, 24.0, bitmap);
        count = count + 24;
        Sleep(150);
        glutSwapBuffers();
    } while ((count < width) && (count < height));
}

void displayFunction(void) {

    // Clear display window.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Set  graphic objects color to Red or change for your choice

    drawText();
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    drawRectangles();
    drawBitmaps();

    // Execute OpenGL functions
    glFlush();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize GLUT.
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // Set display mode.
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    // Set top-left display-window position.
    glutInitWindowPosition((glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) - width) / 2, (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) - height) / 2);
    // Set display-window width and height.
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    // Create display window.
    glutCreateWindow("Michael Powers - Homework 2");
    // Execute initialization procedure.
    init();
    // Send graphics to display window.
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFunction);
    // Window reshape call
    glutReshapeFunc(winReshapeFcn);
    // Display everything and wait.
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GLUT display function `displayFunction` gets called every time the graphics need to be rendered again. On a real OpenGL app it would be called continuously, controlled by a timer. Here it gets called once when the window it opened. But depending on the OS, it may be called multiple times, for example if the window needs to be refreshed because it got activated.

In the code the animation is controlled by `Sleep(150)` and `glutSwapBuffers()` during the execution of `displayFunction()`. So the application blocks during the animation, but the graphics are still shown because of the `glutSwapBuffers()` calls.

Normally a display function should execute quickly (and never block/wait), and call `glFlush()` and `glutSwapBuffers()` only once at the end.

A better implementation would be: The state of the animation (i.e. the number of clock icons) is stored in a global variable `int state = 0`. `displayFunction()` always draws that number of clocks without waiting, and then exits. Before starting the main loop a *timer* is registered with `glutTimerFunc`, with a function that increments `state`, and then calls `glutPostRedisplay()`. This schedules GLUT to recall the display function. Then the app also remains responsive during the animation, and can be quit by closing the window.

Comment: I went ahead and counted that as solved, though I'm still learning and don't completely understand it.  However, learning that displayFunction is more complicated that I thought it was, I have discovered that moving all computations out of there relieves the problem.

I wish all of the OpenGL how-to and function catalog sites weren't terrible...anyway, thanks!